# Is there a binary search algorithm that takes a unary predicate rather than a search value?

Tags: c++, binary-search

I have this exercise:

> Given an array of integers, find the first missing positive integer in linear time and constant space. In other words, find the lowest positive integer that does not exist in the array. The array can contain duplicates and negative numbers as well.
> For example, input `[3, 4, -1, 1]` should give `2` and input `[1, 2, 0]` should give `3`.
> You can modify the input array in-place.

My implementation:

```cpp
template <typename In_It>
int missingPositiveInt(In_It first, In_It last){
    first = std::find_if( first, last, [](int x){return x > 0;} );
    if(first == last || *first > 1)
        return 1;
    for( auto next = first; (++next != last) && ( !(*next - *first > 1) ); )
        ++first;

    return *first + 1;
}

int main(){

    std::vector<int> v{5, 2, -1, 7, 0};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << missingPositiveInt(v.cbegin(), v.cend()) << '\n';

    v = {2, -1, 1, 0};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << missingPositiveInt(v.cbegin(), v.cend()) << '\n';

    v = {5, 2, -1, 7, 0};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << missingPositiveInt(v.cbegin(), v.cend()) << '\n';

    v = {3, 4, -1, 1};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << missingPositiveInt(v.cbegin(), v.cend()) << '\n';

    v = {1, 2, 0};
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << missingPositiveInt(v.cbegin(), v.cend()) << '\n';

    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The output:

```
1
3
1
2
3
```

The program works just fine but I use the algorithm `std::find_if` to find the first positive value in the sequence (sorted sequence) and that algorithm does a linear search.

- As long as the input sequence is already sorted I want to use some binary search algorithm to speed the process.
- I tried using `std::binary_search` but it requires an argument to be searched for. What I need is to get a version that takes a unary predicate and applies a binary search or any other faster algorithm to find the lowest positive value in the sequence so I can write:

  ```
  auto it = binary_search(first, last, [](int x){ return x > 0; });
  ```

Is it possible? Is my code fine or I need to modify it. So any suggestion, hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Linear time? But sorting alone takes more than linear time, doesn’t it?

Comment: There should be a binary search algorithm in the library that you can call with a unary predicate, but there isn't.  Even if there was, though, that's not going to get you to linear time here.

Comment: @numzero with the code in the question yes, but an array of integers can be sorted in linear time

Comment: `std::binary_search` just returns a bool, not the iterator. `std::lower_bound(first, last, 1)` may be what you're looking for in your case.

Comment: @MattTimmermans: Apart from the question is there a way to implement my binary search algorithm that takes a unary predicate rather than a requested value?

Comment: @harold If you mean the counting sort, it doesn’t exactly fit in a constant space unless the values are bounded beforehand (and in practical terms, 2^63 or even 2^31 is not a good bound).

Comment: @Rish: Great! I've used it and worked like a charm:  `first = std::lower_bound(first, last, 1);`

Comment: There must be some trick using the array itself as a storage (that *is* allowed so the space is not strictly constant, but still limited).

Comment: This is not a "binary search" problem. You will note that none of the example arrays are sorted. A binary search only works on ***sorted arrays***. The correct solution to this coding puzzle will have nothing to do, whatsoever, with any binary search. This is a trick question, and the answer should be very obvious, once you take a moment to think through the task at hand, logically.

Comment: @numzero there's also in-place radix sort

Comment: @harold Nice to know that. Looks like (in the binary version) a quicksort with pivoting in the middle of *value* range, that’s how *O(n log n)* (avg.) becomes *O(n log v)* (worst) where *v* is the whole value range.

Comment: You've over-thought the problem and posted an XY problem  (you want to do X [the exercise], incorrectly believe Y [using `binary_search()`] provides a solution, then ask how to achieve Y).   And your solution, by using `std::sort()` is worse than linear time before you even use `binary_search()`.   The real solution to the problem is actually much simpler, and does not involve sorting or a binary search.

Comment: @Peter: This is not my homework. But I only wanted to find a solution that is effective. So what is your suggested simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [std::partition_point](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Partial solution based on @numzero's answer. This doesn't handle negative numbers or zero in the array but you can handle that by linearly preprocessing the array to remove them beforehand. It just marks each index as "found" by negating it, then later looks for the first non negative value and thats the one. Even though its a partial solution it shows the core algorithm.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int arr[] = {1, 4, 6, 7, 2, 7, 7, 8, 3};
    
    int arrSize = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    
    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; ++i)
    {
        int val = abs(arr[i]);
        if(val > 0 && val-1 < arrSize)
        {
            if (arr[val-1]>0)
            {
                arr[val-1] = -arr[val-1];
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<arrSize; ++i)
    {
        if(arr[i] > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Smallest is " << (i+1) << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "Nothing found!" << std::endl;
    
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```